# CNN using tensorflow from_tensor_slices

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, dataset, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to make a classification CNN using image data. I have 10,000 images, which I've divided up into 8,000 for training and 2,000 for validation. They start out as simple numpy arrays with shape (8000, 192, 192) and (2000, 192, 192) respectively. I'm trying to load them into TF following [this documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/numpy). It loads correctly and runs fine with a fully-connected network but I run into issues when I try to replace the `Flatten` layer with a `Conv2D` layer.

I load the images into TF datasets using:

```
train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((train, train_labels))
test_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((validation, validation_labels))
```

The model I'm trying to run is:

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32,(3,3),input_shape=(192, 192)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(2**9, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10)
])
```

This fails immediately with the following error:

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer conv2d is incompatible with the layer: : expected min_ndim=4, found ndim=3. Full shape received: (None, 192, 192)
```

I read that this relates to the shape of the data going into the network, so I tried adding a layer that reshapes the images before going into the convolutional laye:

```
tf.keras.layers.Reshape((-1, 192, 192, 1), input_shape=(192,192))
```

The model builds and compiles when this is added (seemingly no matter numbers I actually put into the reshape layer), but then when I try to fit it, I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Dimension size must be evenly divisible by 7077888 but is 36864 for '{{node sequential_1/reshape/Reshape}} = Reshape[T=DT_FLOAT, Tshape=DT_INT32](sequential_1/Cast, sequential_1/reshape/Reshape/shape)' with input shapes: [192,192], [5] and with input tensors computed as partial shapes: input[1] = [192,?,192,192,1].
```

I can't seem to find any examples of datasets created using `tensors_from_slices` being used with CNNs, only with fully connected networks.

1. Why do these datasets work fine for fully connected networks but not CNNs?
2. Is there a better way to load numpy arrays into TF?
3. If not, how do I reshape the data correctly?

In case it's relevant: I'm using a Google Colab notebook that has Python 3.7 and TensorFlow 2

Comment: Your input shape to the 2D Conv is wrong. Your `input_shape` should be 3D input.

Comment: This question is a bit hard to follow. Please provide a complete minimal example that reproduces the error. From the last error it seems that your data shape is messed up (it shows five dimensions).

Answer (score 0):

https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/numpy
you must set the BATCH_SIZE like this, if you don't need BATCH_SIZE, just set number to the size of whole data

BATCH_SIZE = 64
train_dataset = train_dataset.batch(BATCH_SIZE)